# How to join vertices of two objects

Tags: modeling, vertices

Is there is more automated and accurate way to connect two vertices of neighbouring objects?

I tried to move them manually, but it is a bit difficult to do it just in point.

I'd like to make flat and smooth faces for the bottom and sides. The top face is going to climb a bit to align with vertices of the other - higher object...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use *Snap during transform* tool set to *Vertex*.

Then you can snap directly one point to another or just choosen axis for example <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> then hover desired vertices.

And if you want to trully connect them then you should have meshes joined and after Snap hit <kbd>W</kbd> and *Remove Doubles*.

[image: Snap]

Comment: Try different option as well like edge or face snap, it's really useful tool and if my answer was good enough, consider accepting it or/and upvoting ;)

Comment: After joining them, don't forget to remove the extra edges or at least the internal faces

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to select the two vertices you want to connect/merge (you can use the circle select by pressing C or border select by pressing B) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (shortcut for merging vertices).

Then choose where to merge - center of the distance between the two, at cursor or collapse (I am not quite sure what the difference is between collapse and center). There is no need to later delete extra vertices.